# query to find the cases of cholera by age

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

I have two tables:

```
tbl_1
ID,schoolid,schoolname,district,date,sex,age,weight,symptoms,diagnose

tbl_2
ID,district,patientid,visitdate,sex,age,weight,bpsystolic,diastolic,symptoms,diagnose
```

Now I want to write a query find all the cases of cholera by age and sex from the two tables. I have tried many queries but still no luck.

Thank you.

Comment: There is not enough information. What is the relationship between the two tables (assuming that there is a link between the two)? Exactly what information are you trying to get out?

Comment: The first table contains data reported as notifiable disease surveillance, the second table contains data reported by schools as notifiable cases..i want show all the cases of cholera for example, which is found in diagnose column reported in both tables,age groups, and sex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use the UNION ALL Command.  This links the results of two select statements.

```
SELECT id, schoolid, sex, age, diagnose FROM tbl_1 WHERE diagnose = 'Cholera'
UNION ALL
SELECT id, patientid, sex, age, diagnose  FROM tbl_2 WHERE diagnose = 'Cholera'
ORDER BY age, sex;
```

However you have to have the same number of columns in both SELECT statements and use UNION ALL so it will display all instances of Cholera and not just the first.  They should also have similar data types.

Have a look at the w3schools page for this http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: Please refrain from linking to w3schools, which is widely disliked across StackOverflow (see http://w3fools.com for the reasons why). You might have linked to a page that contains correct information, but the site has a lot of incorrect and misleading information - and linking to w3schools in any way gives it credibility it does **not** deserve